# Unload Statement does NOT Unload UserForm

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm sure this has a simple answer but it has me stumped. The following code is part of a user form I'm making in VBA. The form asks the user for the name of an item in one field, and the quantity of that item in another field. This code is part of what runs when the user clicks "okay" after entering that information. The If-Else Statement show below checks to see if the item (ItemName) appears on a sheet called Inventory. If it does not appear, then the user should see an error message, and the code should stop running. But, my code doesn't stop running. It seems to ignore that "Unload Me" line and keep right on going to the code after the If-Else Statement. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Private Sub cmdOkay_Click()

        Dim Quantity As Double
        Dim ItemName as String
        Dim FoundRange As Range

        ItemName = Item_Name_Field
        Quantity = Quantity_Field

        Sheets("Inventory").Select
        Range("A1").Select

        Set FoundRange = Cells.Find(What:=ItemName, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If FoundRange Is Nothing Then

        Dim AlertBox As Double
        AlertBox = MsgBox(ItemName & " was not found in Inventory. Check your spelling and try again.", vbExclamation, "Item Not Found")
        Unload Me

        Else

      '....
      '(more code)

       End If
      '(more code)
End Sub
```

Comment: @svenoaks that doesn't really make any sense in context... if you're not familiar with VBA, why make suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Put a breakpoint on the line `If FoundRange Is Nothing` and examine the `FoundRange.Address` property in the Locals window of your VBE (or do `Debug.Print FoundRange.Address`).  The only thing that makes sense is that this ItemName **is** found in the worksheet.

Comment: @svenoaks I'm not suggesting you don't try to help, only that if you really are unfamiliar with a subject, your help is not going to be helpful. This is why I don't answer questions on python or c#, etc.  Note: OP explained this is not part of a "function", it is part of an event handler for a button on a user-form.

Comment: Try `Unload UserForm_Name` (modify to use the actual name of your userform). Does that do anything?

Comment: David, the error message is being displayed properly, so ItemName is not found in the Inventory sheet. The problem is that after displaying the error message, the code keeps right on running past the if/else statement. The name of the user form is "Purchase_Returns". I have tried replacing Unload Me with Unload Purchase_Returns, and that has not worked.

Comment: What happens when you step through the code line by line?

Comment: Also, try saving & closing your file, then re-open it. I just tested this method, and it works exactly the way I would expect it to work. `Unload Me` should terminate the form.  What is the name of this procedure?  Is this the command button's `_Click` event handler?

Comment: No luck with saving and reopening. Yes, it's a _Click event. The code begins with Private Sub cmdOkay_Click()

Comment: OK, you might want to revise your Q to include that detail. I've edited your question *title* to be more informative/specific. I am not sure what the problem might be, like I said when i attempt something similar, it works.  Can you answer **What happens when you step through the code line by line?**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "step through" line by line. I just started learning VBA about 2 weeks ago. Would there be some sort of "step through" option in Excel's VBA editor..?

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: YEs, you need to first put a breakpoint and then the code will "stop" (pause) at that point, allowing you to use the F8 key to step line-by-line through the code. Check the link above which has some awesome tips for debugging especially for beginners.

Comment: Adding in my 2 cents - the code works fine for me, userform unload without issue (I called the form by .show with a button).  How did you call the userform?  Also, are you using excel 2003 or lower version?

Comment: The userform is called by a macro which includes nothing but the code "Purchase_Returns.show" and I'm using excel 2010.  I'll read over that link, Dave. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so, when I go through the code line by line, here's what happens when that "Unload Me" line is reached. When that line executes, the userform closes. So, it's not just being ignored. But, the code continues to run. So it picks up again after the If/Else statement. I don't want any code after "Unload Me" to run. Maybe there's a different command for that...? End, Exit, Stop, or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Exit Sub** should get you the desired result:

```
    Dim AlertBox As Double
    AlertBox = MsgBox(ItemName & " was not found in Inventory. Check your spelling and try again.", vbExclamation, "Item Not Found")
    Unload Me
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thanks man; that worked! I knew the answer was simple. Maybe I just wasn't asking my question clearly enough. Thanks again.